# How to make outer div doesn't react when inner div is :active in css

Tags: html, css

I have two div's inside each other. The outer one is bigger When I click on the outer it changes as far as I used .outer:active in css. When I click on the inner it also changes (I used .outer .inner:active), but the outer div changes also.

Here's jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hetjwnxa/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="testimonials-content">
 <div class="testimonials-square">
  <a href="">
      <div class="translation-button">
    <p>Translate</p>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="">
  <div class="testimonials-square-text">
    <p>TITLE</p>
  </div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="testimonials-square">
  <a href="">
      <div class="translation-button">
    <p>Translate</p>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="">
  <div class="testimonials-square-text">
    <p>TITLE</p>
  </div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="testimonials-square">
  <a href="">
      <div class="translation-button">
    <p>Translate</p>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="">
  <div class="testimonials-square-text">
    <p>TITLE</p>
  </div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

And here CSS:

```
.testimonials-content {
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
width: 750px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.testimonials-square {
width: 214px;
height: 214px;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 5px solid #282165;
color: #282165;
font-size: 22px;
text-align: center;
float: left;
margin-right: 26px;
margin-bottom: 27px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
color: #282165;
font-weight: bold;
}

.translation-button {
width: auto;
height: auto;
border-radius: 2px;
border: 2px solid #282165;
color: #282165;
font-size: 22px;
text-align: center;
float: left;
margin: 5px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
color: #282165;
font-weight: bold;
}

.testimonials-square .translation-button p {
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #282165;
}

.testimonials-square-text {
margin-top: 80px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
text-align: center;
}

.testimonials-square p {
color: #282165;
}

.testimonials-square:active {
background-color: #282165;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

.testimonials-square .translation-button:active p {
color: #282165;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.testimonials-square:active p {
background-color: #282165;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

.testimonials-square:nth-child(2n+1) {
background-color: #282165;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

.testimonials-square:nth-child(2n+1) .translation-button {
border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.testimonials-square:nth-child(2n+1) .translation-button p {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
color: #282165;
}

.testimonials-square:nth-child(2n+1) .translation-button:active p {
background-color: #282165;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

.testimonials-square:nth-child(2n+1) p {
background-color: #282165;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

.testimonials-square:nth-child(2n+1):active {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
color: #282165;
}

.testimonials-square:nth-child(2n+1):active p {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
color: #282165;
}

p {
  margin: 0px;
}

a { 
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

How can I make the outer div not to change after clicking on inner div?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle of your problem

Comment: Can you alter the html? There is a solution to your problem if you could place the `.translation-button` outside of the `a` element and then style the `a`, not the `.testimonials-square`.

Answer (score 0):

When an element is `:active`, all it's ancestor elements will be `:active` too, for obvious reasons.

In your case, if you have access to the `HTML`, you could add an extra element (e.g. `.testimonials-bg`) inside the `.testimonials-square` as a sibling to `.translation-button` and style it so it stretches to fit `.testimonials-square` and add the `:active` style to it.

HTML

```
<div class="testimonials-content">
  <div class="testimonials-bg"></div>
  <div class="testimonials-square">
    <a href="">
      <div class="translation-button">
        <p>Translate</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div class="testimonials-square-text">
        <p>TITLE</p>
      </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.testimonials-bg {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
.testimonials-bg:active {
  background-color: #282165;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is:
onmousedown event of the inner div, set the styles of outer div property back to normal.
onmouseup event of inner div, set style of inner div = ""; otherwise the outer div active styles will not work.